# Keeping Row names when using as.data.frame.matrix

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following data set:

```
Date<-c("9/7/2010","9/7/2010","9/7/2010",
        "9/7/2010","9/7/2010","9/7/2010","9/8/2010")
EstimatedQuantity<-c(3535,2772,3279,3411,3484,3274,3305)
ScowNo<-c("4001","3002","4002","BR 8","4002","BR 8","4001")

dataset<- data.frame(EstimatedQuantity,Date,ScowNo)
```

I'm trying to convert the data set into a contingency table and then back into a regular data frame:

```
xtabdata<-as.data.frame.matrix(xtabs(EstimatedQuantity~Date+ScowNo,
                                     data=dataset),
                               row.names=(dataset$Date),optional=F)
```

Answer (score 5):

Is this what you want?

```
as.data.frame(unclass(xtabs(EstimatedQuantity~Date+ScowNo,data=dataset)))
```

Comment: `unclass` is the killer!